# The prime spectrume of integral-valued polynomial ring

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory, ac.commutative-algebra, polynomials, algebraic-number-theory

Let $ D $ be an integral domain with quotiont field $K $ and let $Int (D) $be the set of all integral-valued polynomials on $D $, that is, $ Int (D):=\{f \in K[x]\mid f (D) \subseteq D\} $. The structure of prime spectrum of $Int (D) $  is well-known for a Noetherian local one dimensional domain. Is there any characterization for the prime spectrum of $Int (D) $ without Noetherian local one dimensional assumptions? Thanks  for any help.